# Rake task: NoMethodError: undefined method `tagged' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

Why am I getting a undefined method tagged for nil? Obviously, Rails.logger is returning nil, but why?  I'm getting this error on Heroku on deploy.

```
ENVIRONMENT TASK IS RUN!
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `tagged' for nil:NilClass
/app/lib/tasks/review_app.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => review_app:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

#### Rake File:

```
namespace :review_app do
  desc 'Ensure environment is one we shish to spread seed in'
  task :ensure_review_app do
    abort 'This is not a Heroku Review App' unless review_app?
  end

  task :environment do
    puts 'ENVIRONMENT TASK IS RUN!'
  end

  desc 'Seeds a review app with a subset of realistic-looking data'
  task :seed, [] => %w[
    ensure_review_app
    environment
  ] do
    Rails.logger.tagged('Seed App') { |l| l.info("Finished seeding new Review App: #{ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME']}") }
  end

  def review_app?
    !!ENV['HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME']
  end
end
```

Comment: What's up with that dummy environment task? Does it shadow the built-in task? Try removing it.

Comment: I removed it, but same issue. I also tried `task seed: :environment, [] => %w[`, and got a different error, `NoMethodError: undefined method `tail' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I think something is wrong with this syntax:   `task :seed => :environment, [] => %w[ ensure_review_app ] do` but what?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you were right, I needed to remove the seperate environment task, and not add environment from the top, as it's being added from the array.